# Moving Slides with arrow and mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

Can Anyone help me change the way this example works? I mean I want that when I scroll with mouse wheel or arrows to move from left to the right and not from the top to the bottom... How can I achieve that? I tried all day today but it seems I'm not having succeed on finding the right solution. Also if anyone have other idea hot to achieve what I'm aiming for let me know :)

```js
function scrollModal() {

    var $window = $(window);
    var $document = $(document);
    //Only links that starts with #
    var $navButtons = $(".modalNavLink").filter("[href^=\\#]");
    var $navGoPrev = $(".go-prev");
    var $navGoNext = $(".go-next");
    var $slidesContainer = $(".slides-container");
    var $slides = $(".slide");
    var $currentSlide = $slides.first();

    //Animating flag - is our app animating
    var isAnimating = false;

    //The height of the window
    var pageHeight = $window.innerHeight();

    //Key codes for up and down arrows on keyboard. We'll be using this to navigate change slides using the keyboard
    var keyCodes = {
        UP  : 38,
        DOWN: 40
    }


    // Going to the first slide
    goToSlide($currentSlide);


    $window.on("resize", onResize).resize();
    $window.on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", onMouseWheel);
    $document.on("keydown", onKeyDown);
    $navButtons.on("click", onNavButtonClick);
    $navGoPrev.on("click", goToPrevSlide);
    $navGoNext.on("click", goToNextSlide);



    function onNavButtonClick(event)
    {
        //The clicked button
        var $button = $(this);

        //The slide the button points to
        var $slide = $($button.attr("href"));

        //If the slide exists, we go to it
        if($slide.length)
        {
            goToSlide($slide);
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }; // END onNavButtonClick



    // onKeyDown ===========================================================
    // Getting the pressed key. Only if it's up or down arrow, we go to prev or next slide and prevent default behaviour
    // This way, if there's text input, the user is still able to fill it
    function onKeyDown(event)
    {

        var PRESSED_KEY = event.keyCode;

        if(PRESSED_KEY == keyCodes.UP || PRESSED_KEY == 37)
        {
            goToPrevSlide();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else if(PRESSED_KEY == keyCodes.DOWN || PRESSED_KEY == 39)
        {
            goToNextSlide();
            event.preventDefault();
        }

    }; // END onKeyDown



    // onMouseWheel ===========================================================
    // When user scrolls with the mouse, we have to change slides
    function onMouseWheel(event)
    {
        //Normalize event wheel delta
        var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 30 || -event.originalEvent.detail;

        //If the user scrolled up, it goes to previous slide, otherwise - to next slide
        if(delta < -1)
        {
            goToNextSlide();
        }
        else if(delta > 1)
        {
            goToPrevSlide();
        }

        event.preventDefault();
    }; // END onMouseWheel



    // goToPrevSlide ===========================================================
    // If there's a previous slide, slide to it
    function goToPrevSlide()
    {
        if($currentSlide.prev().length)
        {
            goToSlide($currentSlide.prev());
        }
    }; // END goToPrevSlide


    // goToNextSlide ===========================================================
    // If there's a next slide, slide to it
    function goToNextSlide()
    {
        if($currentSlide.next().length)
        {
            goToSlide($currentSlide.next());
        }
    }; // END goToNextSlide



    // goToSlide ===============================================================
    // Actual transition between slides
    function goToSlide($slide)
    {
        // If the slides are not changing and there's such a slide
        if(!isAnimating && $slide.length)
        {
            //setting animating flag to true
            isAnimating = true;
            $currentSlide = $slide;

            //Sliding to current slide
            TweenLite.to($slidesContainer, 1, {scrollTo: {y: pageHeight * $currentSlide.index() }, onComplete: onSlideChangeEnd, onCompleteScope: this});

            //Animating menu items
            TweenLite.to($navButtons.filter(".active"), 0.5, {className: "-=active"});

            TweenLite.to($navButtons.filter("[href=\\#" + $currentSlide.attr("id") + "]"), 0.5, {className: "+=active"});

        }
    }; // END goToSlide




    // onSlideChangeEnd ========================================================
    // Once the sliding is finished, we need to restore "isAnimating" flag.
    // You can also do other things in this function, such as changing page title
    function onSlideChangeEnd()
    {
        isAnimating = false;
    }; // END onSlideChangeEnd

    // When user resize it's browser we need to know the new height, so we can properly align the current slide
    function onResize(event)
    {

        // This will give us the new height of the window
        var newPageHeight = $window.innerHeight();

        // If the new height is different from the old height ( the browser is resized vertically ), the slides are resized
        if(pageHeight !== newPageHeight)
        {
            pageHeight = newPageHeight;

            //This can be done via CSS only, but fails into some old browsers, so I prefer to set height via JS
            TweenLite.set([$slidesContainer, $slides], {height: pageHeight + "px"});

            //The current slide should be always on the top
            TweenLite.set($slidesContainer, {scrollTo: {y: pageHeight * $currentSlide.index() }});
        }};};

            scrollModal();
```

```css
body, div, p{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
      }

      body{
        font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300;
        letter-spacing: 0.0635em;
      }
      a{
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      .slides-container{
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top:0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 10;

      }

      .slide{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .slide .centered{
        width: 60%;
        margin: 200px auto 0;
      }

      .slide .centered h1{
        text-align: center;
      }

      .slide .centered p{
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 20px;
        font-size: 20px;
      }
      #slide-1{
        background-color:#ffffff;

      }
      #slide-2{
        background-color: #45949b;
      }
      #slide-3{
        background-color: #778899;
      }
      #slide-4{
        color:#ffffff;
        background-color: #291F37;
      }

      .go-prev, .go-next{
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: underline;
      }

      nav{
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        right: 0;
        width: 45px;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        z-index: 999;
      }
      nav ul{
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0;
        margin: auto;

      }

      nav ul li{
        display: block;
      }
      nav ul li:last-child{
        margin-left: 0;
      }
      #back-to-tutorial{
        margin-left: 100px;
      }
      nav a{
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #114469;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: none;
        color:#114469;
      }

      nav a.active{
        background-color: #08385d;
        border: 1px solid #c00000;
      }

      @media and all(max-width:400px) {
        nav ul{
          margin-top: 18px;
        }
        nav ul li{
          margin-right:10px;
          margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        nav a{
          padding: 0px 6px;
          font-size: 14px;
        }

      }

      @media all and (min-width:401px) {
        nav ul{
          margin-top: 23px;
        }
        nav ul li{
          margin-right: 15px;
          margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
        nav a{
          padding: 0px 8px;
          font-size: 18px;
        }
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.11.6/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.11.6/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.11.6/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#slide-1" class="modalNavLink">&nbsp</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide-2" class="modalNavLink">&nbsp</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide-3" class="modalNavLink">&nbsp</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide-4" class="modalNavLink">&nbsp</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="slides-container">
      <div class="slide" id="slide-1">
        <div class="centered">
          <h1>fullscreen slides with GSAP</h1>
          <p>lets go to the <span class="go-next">next slide</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slide" id="slide-2">
        <div class="centered">
          <h1>fullscreen slides with GSAP</h1>
          <p>lets go to the <span class="go-prev">next slide</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slide" id="slide-3">
        <div class="centered">
          <h1>fullscreen slides with GSAP</h1>
          <p>lets go to the <span class="go-next">next slide</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slide" id="slide-1">
        <div class="centered">
          <h1>fullscreen slides with GSAP</h1>
          <p>lets go to the <span class="go-next">next slide</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I didn't know where to add these scripts:
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>

Comment: This is a code dump please ask something specific.

Comment: @Arianna22 to add external JS or CSS file :- edit your question >  click "edit the above snippet" > click "Add an external ibrary" button & give URLs

Comment: It's working now thank you! Also do you know how to make It move to the right slides not at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using the TweenLite plugin from GSAP and you probably didn't include their core scripts in your html file.

so you need to include this in your page.html code

```html
<head>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/jquery.gsap.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TweenLite.min.js"> </script>
</head>
```

Comment: No I did... I just didn't know how to included it here in stack since im new member :)